# How to calculate payu hash with jquery

Tags: jquery, hash, checksum, payu

How to calculate payu hash with jquery.
Checksum Error is come.
I tried it using jquery to calculate hash and then submit it to payu but

"Error. We are sorry we are unable to process your payment.

Checksum Failed. Please contact your merchant."
error come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a space in hash string.I trimmed the hash with jquery $.trim

Answer (score 1):

You can compute hash in JavaScript with CrytoJS.

```
var sigValue = $('input[name="parameter_1"').val() + $('input[name="session_id"').val() (...);

var passhash = CryptoJS.MD5(sigValue);
```